# Does EaselJS removeChild also remove attached eventListeners?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, garbage-collection, dom-events, easeljs

Does EaselJS's `removeChild` method, (part of [Stage](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html)), handle cleanup of eventListeners attached to that child, as well?  Or must you manually remove the child's event listeners using `removeEventListener` before removing the child?

For example:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
circle = new createjs.Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill("#333").drawCircle(0,0,5);

circle.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){
    console.log("mouse down");
});
stage.addChild(circle);
.
.
.
stage.removeChild(circle);
```

Answer (score 8):

EventListeners are not removed upon `removeChild()`, as they are also not added upon `addChild()` - If you do want to quickly remove them all, the quickest way would be `myChild.removeAllEventListeners();`

However if a DisplayObject is not attached to the Stage somehow, events won't be dispatched by mouse-interactions, because those only bubble through the stage and its' children.

In case you worry about memory-leaks: Events in EaselJS are sitting directly on the DisplayObject itself, so whenever you delete the reference to that Object, the Events will(should) be collected by the GarbageCollecter as well, no need for removing events separately. *(please, someone correct me here, in case I'm wrong)*

Comment: So in essence, if the only reference to a child was from the parent, using `removeChild()`, should, in fact, remove the Event Listener by way of garbage collection?

Comment: Yes, I'm 95% sure about that and never had any issues, but if you want to be super-save, just add an `removeAllEventListeners()` - won't hurt that much ;-)